# mind mapping tool in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mindmapping

I want to do mindmaps which are of the quality of mindmeister that you could include picture and links etc and would be able to export it reasonably well and print it.

Comment: A possible alternative would be to use a virtual machine.

Comment: @all, would anybody like to say something that why is it down voted?

Comment: I tried a few options, and finally went with [xournal](https://github.com/dmgerman/xournal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer Freeplane but FreeMind can do the same things:

- http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/FreeMind_on_Linux
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeplane/

Answer (score 3):

I love X-Mind. I don't know if it does what you need, but I only use a small subset of it and still it rocks!

It has a very complete free version that never expires and doesn't contain crapware.

http://www.xmind.net/download/linux/

Comment: thanks, but its not free

Comment: It's not 100% free, but like I said, I've been using it for years without issues, and it surely is worth a try (GUI is much more polished and straightforward than any similar I've tried, even paid ones).